# Does thermistor resistance vary with excitation current?

Tags: thermistor

I am looking to use this thermistor for my temperature measurement application - https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Cantherm%20PDFs/STS1_Series.pdf

The spec sheet mentions that the operating current required is 1 mA. However, I only have 0.1 mA source (Through NI 9226). Can I still use this thermistor for my application and rely on the table provided for resistance to temp conversion?

Comment: The quick answer I believe is that it should be fine. 1mA is mentioned on the datasheet as that's what they used to test/prove out the device. Though it is worth noteing that the excitation current can have an impact: higher currents will cause self heating of the thermistor/RTD, so it's best to use the lower current you can reliably use (generate as a stable current and generate a suitable readable voltage). No doubt someone with more time will give you a more complete answer.

Comment: What temperature range do you need to measure?

Answer (score 6):

**SHORT ANSWER:** For temperatures of up to 150°C it should be fine.

**DETAILED ANSWER:** The datasheet claims that the product has the same behaviour as KTY84 for temperatures of up to 170°C, and the linearity might be lost above 170°C, although it's characterised for 1 mA of drive current. From the graph given in the datasheet the resistance approaches 1.5 kiloohm at 170°C.

[image]

If we look at [KTY84](https://www.goldenmotor.com/certs/KTY84_SER.pdf) we can see the same, at least for drive currents of at least 0.5 mA:

[image]

For 0.1 mA of drive current, the curve will be between 0.5 mA and -1 mA but it's difficult to estimate the temperature that the curve starts to "rotate". For -1 mA, for example, the linearity is lost above 150°C. So, for 0.1mA, we can expect to lose the linearity somewhere between 150°C and 220°C.

Apparently, it's safe to say that the curve is valid for up to 150°C and for a drive current of 0.1 mA. If your application requires measurement above 150°C then you can't use this sensor with 0.1mA of drive current.